# CCLabelBMFont fails on setString with update

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have Cocos2d app that fail randomly for some user when i try to display a CCLabelBMFont with animation. I'm not able to reproduce the issue on any of my test device. Since it seem to fail on line 845 I'm wondering if I'm runing out of mmemory. I'm using cocos2d v2.0.0.

```
for (TileBlockModel* tile in [matchInfo tiles]) {
    if (tile.matchScore > 0 && tile.spriteObject != nil) {
        NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",tile.matchScore];
        CCLabelBMFont* label = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:str fntFile:@"8-WHITE NUMBERS.fnt"];
        label.position = ((CCNode*)tile.spriteObject).position;
        label.scale = label.scale * fontMultiplier;
        label.zOrder = TILE_BLOCK_SCORE_Z_LEVEL;
        [gameGrid addChild:label];
        CCActionInterval* action = [CCSequence actions:
                            [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:.4 position:ccp(0, ((CCNode*)tile.spriteObject).boundingBox.size.height)],
                                    [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode* node){
            [node removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
        }],
                            nil];
        [label runAction:[CCSpeedPointer actionWithAction:action speed_:globalGameSpeed]];

    }

}
```

Crash log

```
0     vault2richesiphone                    0x00078a02 -[CCLabelBMFont setString:updateLabel:] (CCLabelBMFont.m:845)
1     vault2richesiphone                    0x00078d29 -[CCLabelBMFont setFntFile:] (CCLabelBMFont.m:921)
2     vault2richesiphone                    0x00077f1d -[CCLabelBMFont updateLabel] (CCLabelBMFont.m:622)
3     vault2richesiphone                    0x000b58b3 -[gameViewController displayMatchScore:] (gameViewController.m:1100)
4     vault2richesiphone                    0x000b68ab -[gameViewController animateColumnDrop:andRow:andOffset:animationId:] (gameViewController.m:1226)
5     vault2richesiphone                    0x0006755d -[CCRepeat stop] (CCActionInterval.m:307)
6     vault2richesiphone                    0x0006c4bf -[CCProgressTo startWithTarget:] (CCActionProgressTimer.m:53)
7     vault2richesiphone                    0x0008ca59 +[CCShaderCache sharedShaderCache] (CCShaderCache.m:41)
8     vault2richesiphone                    0x000a070d -[CCDirectorIOS setProjection:] (CCDirectorIOS.m:217)
9     QuartzCore                            0x3581c7a9 _ZN2CA7Display11DisplayLink8dispatchEyy + 161
10   QuartzCore                             0x3581c701 _ZN2CA7Display16IOMFBDisplayLink8callbackEP21__IOMobileFramebufferyyyPv + 65
11   IOMobileFramebuffer                    0x37a98fd7 IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 155
12   IOKit                                  0x3480f5ad IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 193
13   CoreFoundation                         0x33bf188b __CFMachPortPerform + 119
14   CoreFoundation                         0x33bfc3e7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 35
15   CoreFoundation                         0x33bfc38b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 139
16   CoreFoundation                         0x33bfb20f __CFRunLoopRun + 1383
17   CoreFoundation                         0x33b6e23d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
18   CoreFoundation                         0x33b6e0c9 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
19   GraphicsServices                       0x3774d33b GSEventRunModal + 75
20   UIKit                                  0x35a8a2b9 UIApplicationMain + 1121
```

Comment: Without knowing the exact cocos2d version the line number is not helpful, in my version line 845 is a comment. Just quote the line 845 plus surrounding lines from your CCLabelBMFont.m.

Comment: Like shooting darts with a blindfold. However, memory highly unlikely if it is always the same line of code that bombs. If i was a gambling man, i'd look for a zombie. The stacktrace does not seem to be related to the snippet of code. Go look at line 1100 of gameViewController.

Comment: I'm using cocos2d v2.0.0